# How to count frequencies/occurences of all values within a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I need a count of all the emails in a list, some of the emails however are consolidated together with a `|` symbol. These need to be split and the emails need to be counted after splitting to avoid getting an inaccurate or low count of frequencies.

I have a list that is something like this:

```
test = ['abc@gmail.com', 'xyz@jad.com|abc@gmail.com', 'asd@ajf.com|abc@gmail.com', 'asdf@adh.com', 'xyz@jad.com']
```

I performed a set of operations to split and when I split, the pipe gets replaced by double quotes at that location so I replace the double with single quotes so I have all email ids enclosed in single quotes.

```
# convert list to a string
test_str = str(test)

# apply string operation to split by separator '|'
test1 = test_str.split('|')
print(test1)

--> OUTPUT of above print statement:   ["['abc@gmail.com', 'xyz@jad.com", "abc@gmail.com', 'asd@ajf.com", "abc@gmail.com', 'asdf@adh.com', 'xyz@jad.com']"]

test2 = str(test1)
test3 = test2.replace('"','')
print(test3)

--> OUTPUT of above print statement: [['abc@gmail.com', 'xyz@jad.com', 'abc@gmail.com', 'asd@ajf.com', 'abc@gmail.com', 'asdf@adh.com', 'xyz@jad.com']]
```

How can I now obtain a count of all the emails? This is a string essentially and if it's a list, I could use collections.Counter to easily obtain a count.

I'd like to get a list like the one listed below that has the email and the count in descending order of frequency

```
 ['abc@gmail.com': 3, 'xyz@jad.com': 2, 'asd@ajf.com': 1, 'asdf@adh.com': 1]
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter` with a generator expression that iterates over the input list of strings and then iterates over the sub-list of emails by splitting the strings. Use the `most_common` method to ensure a descending order of counts:

```
from collections import Counter
dict(Counter(e for s in test if s for e in s.split('|')).most_common())
```

This returns:

```
{'abc@gmail.com': 3, 'xyz@jad.com': 2, 'asd@ajf.com': 1, 'asdf@adh.com': 1}
```

Comment: That's great. I have one question. What if the list consists of a NoneType value. test = ['abc@gmail.com', 'xyz@jad.com|abc@gmail.com', None, 'asd@ajf.com|abc@gmail.com', 'asdf@adh.com', 'xyz@jad.com'] How can I get rid of it and use the above function?

Comment: This works btw if there's no None value. Thank you so much.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a filter that filters out `None` items then.

Answer (score 1):

What about iterating over the list and calling `counter.update` on every string? Like this:

```
test = ['abc@gmail.com', 'xyz@jad.com|abc@gmail.com', 'asd@ajf.com|abc@gmail.com', 'asdf@adh.com', 'xyz@jad.com']
c = Counter()
for email_str in test:
    if email_str:
        c.update(email_str.split('|'))
res = c.most_common()
```

Comment: that works too for the current list! Thanks! however if there's a None value that would not work. How can I make it work with a None type value in my list?

Comment: super thanks so much! I appreciate the help and quick response. Got to finish my code!